# Difference between top level Work Item and Backlog Work Item in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

What is the difference between Work Item at the top level and Work Item in Backlog? Top level Work Items seem to have no use in sprints etc. Are they for a completely different use not related to product development?

Creating a Work Item from the Backlog screen makes it visible in Work Items at the top.

Creating a Work Item at the top (clicking on Work Items, then new Work Item) does not make it visible in the Backlog list of Work Items.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked on Scrum process and on the backlog you can add only these two Work Item Types:
[image]

If you add them on top level, they will also appear here. However if you on top level you will add different types of WIT they will not appear in Backlog.

Comment: thanks for that but what's the difference between a top level Work Item and a Backlog Work Item? The former is invisible to the agile process and cannot be added to a sprint Why is it there?

Comment: What process do you use? Scrum? Can you detail what you mean by saying Work Item at the top level and Work Item in Backlog?

Comment: I've added a screenshot to the question and some more info. Creating a Work Item when in the Work Items screen (top level) doesn't seem to have any use

Comment: good question that got me thinking. I was creating a Task in top level Work Items. Creating a User Story in top level Work Items makes it visible to the Backlog. So different types of Work Items are visible in different parts of the UI. Thanks for the question.

Comment: @codebrane Cool! Can you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful to you?

Comment: have updated your reply as it's the clearest answer I've had to the Work Item differences. Thanks again